# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have to get a graphic from this code, but it seems that something is not working with it.

When I run the code I get this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[]
y=[]

readFile = open("C:/Users/Martinez/Documents/Diego/Python/SampleData.txt","r")

for linea in readFile:
    print linea

sepFile = readFile.read().split("\n")
readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:

    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    x.append(int(xAndY[0]))
    y.append(int(xAndY[1]))


print x
print y
```

Comment: What is in `sepFile`? You have at least one line that does *not* have integers on it.

Comment: Try printing out `sepFile` to make sure you're getting what you expect.  It looks like you're expecting an array of strings, where each string is in the form "int,int".  You might be having problems if some of these lines contains spaces or other characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading each line of the input file in the first `for linea in readFile` loop.  When you try to read the contents again you are only going to get an empty string.  Either eliminate the first for loop, or add `readFile.seek(0)` before the line `sepFile = readFile.read().split("\n")`

A working version of your program would be

```
x = []
y = []
with open("C:/Users/Martinez/Documents/Diego/Python/SampleData.txt") as read_file:
    for line in read_file:
        print line
        a, b = line.split(',')
        x.append(int(a))
        y.append(int(b))

print x
print y
```

To demonstrate the problem a bit further:

```
>>> read_file = open('inp.txt')
>>> for line in read_file:  # reads entire contents of file
...     print line
...
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
>>> read_file.read()  # trying to read again gives an empty string
''
>>> out = read_file.read()
>>> int(out)  # empty string cannot be converted to an int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

>>> read_file.seek(0)  # moves to beginning of file
>>> read_file.read()   # now the content can be read again
'3,4\n5,6\n7,8\n9,10\n'
```